# creating object in c++ using input file

Tags: c++, file

i am mostly familiar with java and c++ is not my strong spot..

I am trying to write algorithm for cpu scheduler most of my code is syntax error free but I am stuck to one problem.

My program uses 2 classes Process and ProcessQueue

my main looks like this

```
int main(){

    fstream f;

    ProcessQueue pq;

    f.open("input.txt");

    if (!f)
    {
        cout << "File not Found";
    }else{
    int noOfProcess;

    f >> noOfProcess;
    Process *p;
    p = new Process[noOfProcess];

    for (int i = 0;i<noOfProcess;i++){
        int arivalTime;
        int cpuTime;
        int prorityNumber;

        f >> arrivalTime;
        f >> cpuTime;
        f >> prorityNumber;

        p[i] = new Process(arrivalTime,cpuTime,prorityNumber);
    }
return 0;
}
```

but p[i] is causing trouble..
I am not able to use parametric constructor,setters.

it gives following error

[image]

Comment: The variable `p` doesn't point to an array of pointers, but an array of *objects*. Try  `p[i] = Process(...)` (without the `new` keyword).

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
p[i] = new Process(arrivalTime,cpuTime,prorityNumber);
```

to

```
p[i] = Process(arrivalTime,cpuTime,prorityNumber);
```

as `p[pi]` is of type `Process`

Also use `std::array` or `str::vector`